# Facebook login with PHP SDK not working

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

let me put my problem in a few words: 
I am trying to build an Facebook application that works as Facebook Page Tab.
When you land on the Page Tab it checks if the current user likes the current page and prints a result accordingly. After I make sure the page is liked I am asking to login via Facebook so that I am getting the user's name and ID. The problem is that the login button works only for me(admin of the page and app).

This is my code:

```
    require_once('*/*/facebook.php');
    $config = array(
    'appId' => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
    'cookie' => true
    );


    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    $me = null;
    if ($uid) {
      try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
      }
    }

    //4. login or logout
    if ($me) {
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
```

And this is my HTML Markup:

```
    <html dir="LTR" lang="bg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="wrapper">           

<?php if ($me): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">LOGOUT</a>
<?php echo 'Welcome, '.$me['name']. '.<br />'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
    LOGIN
  </a>
<?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by using redirect_uri to php file which then redirects back to the page tab. Also used target="_top" for the login link.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the complete source code from the given URL.

[Download Facebook+Twitter Login Script in PHP](http://www.cypherincorporated.co.in/facebook_twitter_login.zip)